# Problem Realizing a proof with the algebraists notation

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

If $G$ is a finite group and $T$ is an automorphism of it, such that:
$T(x)=x \iff x=e$

Prove that:

(i) $G=\{x^{-1}T(x):x\in G\}$
(ii) If $T^2=id$ then $G$ is abelian.

I know that this question DOES have answer, at least i can provide these links:
[Prove that every element of a group G can be represented as $g = x^{-1}(xT)$ for some x $\in$ G?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701615/prove-that-every-element-of-a-group-g-can-be-represented-as-g-x-1xt-for)
[$xT=x$ iff $x=e$ implies that every $g$ may be written as $x^{-1}(xT)$ for some $x\in G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/305284/xt-x-iff-x-e-implies-that-every-g-may-be-written-as-x-1xt-for-some?noredirect=1&lq=1)
But the problem is the notation. I can't understand it. My notation is different. I'm confused at reading that answers. Because they both use some sort of mysterious notation.

Can someone please clarify the answer?

Comment: Why don't you try and answer the question yourself rather than trying to understand previous answers? Just to get you started, to prove (i) it is enough to prove that if $x^{-1}T(x) = y^{-1}T(y)$, then $x=y$.

Comment: The notation is indeed weird. You might want to look at the comments of the first link, there is some discussion about it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ok i'll try (i was trying after all...)

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm looking at those answers from yesterday... i can't understand what they are saying! Can u ?

Comment: In fact, I think all you need to know is that what is written as $xT$ is what you would write $T(x)$.

Comment: Hint: 

For Part (i), show that the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}T(x)$ is injective.  Since you're dealing with a finite set, injectivity is enough to prove that this map is bijective.

Suppose that $x^{-1}T(x)=y^{-1}T(y)$, then by multiplying on the left by $x$ and on the right by $(T(y))^{-1}=T(y^{-1})$, you get $T(x)T(y^{-1})=xy^{-1}$.  Since $T$ is an automorphism, $T(x)T(y^{-1})=T(xy^{-1})$ so $T(xy^{-1})=xy^{-1}$.  By assumption, $xy^{-1}=e$ or $x=y$.  Therefore, the map is injective and hence the sets are equal.